# how to add a note to iphone contact?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, addressbook

I am developing an App that stores contacts in the address book . I would like to add notes field in my implementation , I know that to add a phone number this is the code to be used :

```
ABMultiValueRef multiPhone = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiRealPropertyType);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, (__bridge_retained CFStringRef)Tel, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, (__bridge_retained CFStringRef)Fax, kABPersonPhoneWorkFAXLabel, NULL);

ABRecordSetValue(contact, kABPersonPhoneProperty, multiPhone, nil);
CFRelease(multiPhone);
```

I know that the equivalent of `kABPersonPhoneProperty` is `kABNoteProperty` but what is the equivalent of `kABWorkLabel` for the note field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The note property, identified by `kABNoteProperty`, is a single-value property, not a multi-value property, so there's no corresponding label. The phone property is multi-value: it can contain several different values at the same time, so you need labels to distinguish the values. The note property is like the first name or last name property -- these can only have one value at a time. Use `ABRecordSetValue()` for this:

```
bool ABRecordSetValue (
   ABRecordRef record,
   ABPropertyID property,
   CFTypeRef value,
   CFErrorRef *error
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent of `kABWorkLabel` for `kABNoteProperty`, because the note property is a single string, not a multivalue.

```
CFErrorRef error;
if (!ABRecordSetValue(contact, kABNoteProperty, (__bridge CFStringRef)@"hello world", &error)) {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: ok , so assuming I have a NSString that I want to add as a note , how to add it? I am quite new to iPhone Development ?

Comment: Not sure if this is xcode5 or not but `kABNoteProperty` throws an error for me, it should be `kABPersonNoteProperty`.